# Partial summation formula for two indexes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation-by-parts

We know that partial summation states that given two sequences $(\alpha_n), (\beta_n)$, we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^p\alpha_n\beta_n=\beta_nA_p+\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}(\beta_n-\beta_{n+1})A_n$$

where $A_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\alpha_n$.

Is there a version of this formula for sequences $(\alpha_n^m)$ with two indexes?

Comment: Do you sum over $m$ as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about $\sum_{n,m}\alpha_n^m\beta_n^m$